# Embedding Python in C - Syntax Error line 1 in .py file

Tags: python, c

I have the following lines of code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   FILE * file;

   Py_Initialize();
   file = fopen("LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py","r");
   PyRun_SimpleFile(file,"LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py");

   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

When I run the application, the following is the output.

```
  File "LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py", line 1
    ▒v▒v@▒p
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What seems to be the problem here? I have tried editing in Notepad++ and changed the Encoding but the same thing happens.

We have the same issue with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860783/python-syntaxerror-when-embedding-in-c).

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

Contents of the .py file:

```
#LIFT_Head_move_to_Max
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial(
   port='/dev/ttyS0',
   baudrate=115200,
   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

print(ser.isOpen())

data="\x5A\x10\x10\x02\x40\x00"

ser.write(data)
ser.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Please do not post pictures of plain text.  It is annoying.  Post the plain text as if it were code.  If you don't want any syntax highlighting, include `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on a line on its own with a blank line above and below it before the output.  And the image doesn't show the text in the `.py` file.

Comment: Voting to close: We need to see the contents of `LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py` before we can begin to diagnose this.

Comment: Could you show what is inside the py file, because that is where the error seems to be coming from

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Please see updated question.

Comment: The Python script you show is probably not what's actually on disk.

Comment: @Kevin Please see updated question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I may have failed to understand your comment. I am using Raspberry Pi and it's the one in my directory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about that and thanks for the heads up. Updated the question.

Comment: And you don't have multiple `LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py` files in different directories? If you open the file in a hex-editor, is it correct?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `.py` file is not encoded unusually?  One possible source of trouble could be RTF (rich text format) instead of plain text.  Another might be UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 or 8859-15 or CP1252.  One way to verify this is to do a hex dump of the first few bytes of the file (32 — 64 at most).  Since you're using Notepad++, I suspect you may be on a Windows machine, in which case I'm not sure what the best hex dump tool is.  On a Unix-like machine, I'd suggest `od -c` or `xxd` or something similar (`xxd -u -l 64 -g 1 LIFT_Head_move_to_Max.py`, for example).

Comment: I tried opening in a hex-editor and everything is correct. I have not seen any rubbish hex characters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have done hex dumping. I am working with Raspberry Pi so I used the commands you shared. The same results, though.

Comment: If the file really does contain plain text, then Python is confused.  It is saying that it is seeing something else altogether.  Given a choice between Python being mistaken and you being mistaken, I'm sorry but I trust Python over you.  The difficulty now is working out what's going wrong.  I've not programmed a Raspberry Pi.  Can you upload the file from the Pi and check that what you upload is what you think you downloaded to the Pi?  Have you tested the program — the C you show and the Python script — on a Linux or Windows box? Does it work?  If the `serial` module is a problem, change it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. After some debugging, I found my FILE* is actually null due to the wrong file path. And it threw the confusing `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.  Maybe you should check against that